is it possilbe to run AR(1) model in R with ar is bigger than 1
is it possilbe to run AR(1) model in R when ar(which is pie in AR model) is bigger than 1
i know that arima.sim can run AR(1) model with following codes
airma.sim(n=100, list(ar = 0.3)
but i'd like to know when list(ar > 1), can i run AR(1) model or not ?
if not, i wanna know the methods

If you want to estimate AR(1) model with $\phi>1$ in R, just use dplyr package, which provides lag command to construct lagged time series. For instance, model <-  lm(series ~ dplyr::lag(series)). This will provide AR(1) coefficient regardless of the size of $\phi$.

arima.sim does not allow an AR(1) model with $\phi > 1$.
The reason for this is that it assumes that it can start from $Y_0 = 0$, then simulate for a while (burn-in period) to approximate the long-run stationary distribution. When $\phi > 1$, you don't have a stationary distribution that you approach in the long-run, and that function doesn't support that situation.
This looks like a question about software, but it isn't really: your problem is that fundamentally you haven't fully specified your model because you're missing the initial distribution. That could be a specific normal distribution, or a point mass, or whatever you want. Once you specify the initial distribution, you would simply simulate like this:

Draw $Y_0$ from the initial distribution
For $t=1,...,T$, draw $\varepsilon_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ and compute:

$$Y_t =\mu + \phi Y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$$

Just provide a vector of length greater than one to the ar component of the model parameter:
arima.sim(n=100,list(ar=c(0.5,-0.2)))

